Camera2 API to stream live video as chunks to server Video Encoder issue - MAUI Android
I have implemented a way to upload live stream as chunks to azure server using Android.Hardware.Camera. It's working fine. Now this Camera is deprecated in Android and I am currently using Camera2.
Now I am facing issue in encoding is my guess.
Now the video played is displaying like below,

My Activity class looks like below,
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private const string TAG = "Camera2LiveStream";
    private const int DEFAULT_FRAME_RATE = 15;
    private const int DEFAULT_BIT_RATE = 500000;

    private TextureView _textureView;
    private CameraDevice _cameraDevice;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder _captureRequestBuilder;
    private CameraCaptureSession _cameraCaptureSession;
    private Surface _previewSurface;
    private MediaCodecEncoder _encoder; // Custom encoder for encoding frames
    private bool _isStreaming = false;
    private string _sasUrl = "<url>";
    private List<byte[]> _encDataList = new List<byte[]>();
    private HandlerThread _backgroundThread;
    private Handler _backgroundHandler;
    private const int RequestCameraPermissionId = 100;
    private ImageReader _imageReader;
    private bool isStartedSendingChunks  = false;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        RequestCameraPermission();

        _textureView = FindViewById<TextureView>(Resource.Id.textureView);
        var startStreamButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.startStreamButton);
        startStreamButton.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (_isStreaming)
            {
                StopStream();
                startStreamButton.Text = "Start Stream";
            }
            else
            {
                StartStream();
                startStreamButton.Text = "Stop Stream";
            }
        };
    }

    private void RequestCameraPermission()
    {
        // Check if the camera permission is already granted
        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.Camera) == (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
            // Permission is already granted, proceed with camera-related tasks
            //UseCamera();
        }
        else
        {
            // Request the camera permission
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Manifest.Permission.Camera }, RequestCameraPermissionId);
        }
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == RequestCameraPermissionId)
        {
            if (grantResults.Length > 0 && grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
            {
                // Permission was granted, proceed with camera-related tasks
                //UseCamera();
            }
            else
            {
                // Permission was denied
                Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(this, "Camera permission is required.", Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
    }


    private async void StartStream()
    {
        isStartedSendingChunks = false;
        await CreateAppendBlob();
        _isStreaming = true;
        _encoder = new MediaCodecEncoder();
        await _encoder.Init(1920, 1080, DEFAULT_FRAME_RATE, DEFAULT_BIT_RATE);//1920,1080
        StartBackgroundThread();

        if (_textureView.IsAvailable)
            await OpenCamera();
        else
            _textureView.SurfaceTextureListener = new TextureListener(this);

        new System.Threading.Thread(StreamToAzure).Start();

        Toast.MakeText(this, "Streaming started.", ToastLength.Long).Show();

    }

    private void StopStream()
    {
        isStartedSendingChunks = false;
        _isStreaming = false;
        _encoder?.Close();
        _encoder = null;
        CloseCamera();
        StopBackgroundThread();
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Streaming stopped.", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
    private void CloseCamera()
    {
        _cameraCaptureSession?.Close();
        _cameraCaptureSession = null;

        _cameraDevice?.Close();
        _cameraDevice = null;
    }
    private async Task OpenCamera()
    {
        var cameraManager = (CameraManager)GetSystemService(CameraService);
        string cameraId = cameraManager.GetCameraIdList()[0]; // Assuming the back camera

        var cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.GetCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        var streamConfigMap = (StreamConfigurationMap)cameraCharacteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.ScalerStreamConfigurationMap);
        
        var sizes = streamConfigMap.GetOutputSizes((int)ImageFormatType.Yuv420888)[0];
        var previewSize = streamConfigMap.GetOutputSizes(Class.FromType(typeof(SurfaceTexture)))[0];
        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = _textureView.SurfaceTexture;
        surfaceTexture.SetDefaultBufferSize(sizes.Width, sizes.Height);

        _previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

        // Add ImageReader for frame capture
        _imageReader = ImageReader.NewInstance(previewSize.Width, previewSize.Height, ImageFormatType.Yuv420888, 2);
        _imageReader.SetOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageAvailableListener(this), _backgroundHandler);


        try
        {
            cameraManager.OpenCamera(cameraId, new CameraStateCallback(this), _backgroundHandler);
        }
        catch (CameraAccessException e)
        {
            Log.Error(TAG, e.Message);
        }
    }


    private void StartCameraPreview()
    {
        try
        {
            _captureRequestBuilder = _cameraDevice.CreateCaptureRequest(CameraTemplate.Preview);
            _captureRequestBuilder.AddTarget(_previewSurface);
            _captureRequestBuilder.AddTarget(_imageReader.Surface); // Add ImageReader surface for frame capture

            _cameraDevice.CreateCaptureSession(new List<Surface> { _previewSurface, _imageReader.Surface }, new CaptureSessionCallback(this), _backgroundHandler);

            //_cameraDevice.CreateCaptureSession(new List<Surface> { _previewSurface }, new CaptureSessionCallback(this), _backgroundHandler);
        }
        catch (CameraAccessException e)
        {
            Log.Error(TAG, e.Message);
        }
    }

    private void StartBackgroundThread()
    {
        _backgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
        _backgroundThread.Start();
        _backgroundHandler = new Handler(_backgroundThread.Looper);
    }

    private void StopBackgroundThread()
    {
        _backgroundThread?.QuitSafely();
        _backgroundThread?.Join();
        _backgroundThread = null;
        _backgroundHandler = null;
    }
    private async Task CreateAppendBlob()
    {
        new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                var url = new URL(_sasUrl);
                var connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.OpenConnection();
                connection.RequestMethod = "PUT";
                connection.SetRequestProperty("x-ms-blob-type", "AppendBlob");
                connection.Connect();

                if (connection.ResponseCode == HttpStatus.Created)
                {
                    Log.Info(TAG, "Append Blob created successfully!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Error(TAG, "Failed to create Append Blob: " + connection.ResponseMessage);
                }
                connection.Disconnect();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(TAG, ex.Message);
            }
        }).Start();
    }
    private void StreamToAzure()
    {
        new System.Threading.Thread(async () =>
        {
            while (_isStreaming)
        {
            byte[] encData = null;
            lock (_encDataList)
            {
                if (_encDataList.Count > 0)
                {
                    encData = _encDataList[0];
                    _encDataList.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }

            if (encData != null)
            {
                await UploadToAzure(encData);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
            }
        }
        }).Start();
    }

    private async Task UploadToAzure(byte[] data)
    {
        new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                var url = new URL(_sasUrl + "&comp=appendblock");
                var connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.OpenConnection();
                connection.RequestMethod = "PUT"; 
                //connection.SetRequestProperty("x-ms-blob-type", "AppendBlob");
                connection.SetRequestProperty("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString());
                connection.SetRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
                connection.DoOutput = true;

                var outputStream = connection.OutputStream;
                outputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                outputStream.Close();

                if (connection.ResponseCode == HttpStatus.Created)
                {
                    Log.Info(TAG, "Chunk uploaded successfully!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Error(TAG, "Failed to upload chunk: " + connection.ResponseMessage);
                }
                connection.Disconnect();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(TAG, ex.Message);
            }
        }).Start();
    }

    private async void ProcessFrame(byte[] frameData)
    {
        if (_isStreaming)
        {
                byte[] encodedData = await _encoder.OfferEncoder(frameData);
                if (encodedData?.Length >0 )
                {
                    lock (_encDataList)
                    {
                        _encDataList.Add(encodedData);
                    }
                }
            
        }
    }
    private class TextureListener : Java.Lang.Object, TextureView.ISurfaceTextureListener
    {
        private readonly MainActivity _activity;

        public TextureListener(MainActivity activity) => _activity = activity;

        public void OnSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) => _activity.OpenCamera();

        public bool OnSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) => true;

        public void OnSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) { }

        public void OnSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) { }
    }

    private class CameraStateCallback : CameraDevice.StateCallback
    {
        private readonly MainActivity _activity;

        public CameraStateCallback(MainActivity activity) => _activity = activity;

        public override void OnOpened(CameraDevice camera)
        {
            _activity._cameraDevice = camera;
            _activity.StartCameraPreview();
        }

        public override void OnDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) => camera.Close();

        public override void OnError(CameraDevice camera, CameraError error) => camera.Close();
    }

    private class CaptureSessionCallback : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback
    {
        private readonly MainActivity _activity;

        public CaptureSessionCallback(MainActivity activity) => _activity = activity;

        public override void OnConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session)
        {
            _activity._cameraCaptureSession = session;
            try
            {
                _activity._cameraCaptureSession.SetRepeatingRequest(_activity._captureRequestBuilder.Build(), null, _activity._backgroundHandler);
            }
            catch (CameraAccessException e)
            {
                Log.Error(TAG, e.Message);
            }
        }

        public override void OnConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session)
        {
            Log.Error(TAG, "Camera session configuration failed.");
        }
    }

    private class ImageAvailableListener : Java.Lang.Object, ImageReader.IOnImageAvailableListener
    {
        private readonly MainActivity _activity;

        public ImageAvailableListener(MainActivity activity) => _activity = activity;

        public void OnImageAvailable(ImageReader reader)
        {
            Image image = null;
            try
            {
                image = reader.AcquireLatestImage();
                if (image == null) return;

                int totalSize = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < image.GetPlanes().Length; i++)
                {
                    totalSize += image.GetPlanes()[i].Buffer.Remaining();
                }

                byte[] data = new byte[totalSize];
                int offset = 0;

                // Copy each plane
                foreach (var plane in image.GetPlanes())
                {
                    var buffer = plane.Buffer;
                    int remaining = buffer.Remaining();
                    buffer.Get(data, offset, remaining);
                    offset += remaining;
                }

                _activity.ProcessFrame(data);

                //image = reader.AcquireLatestImage();
                //if (image != null)
                //{
                //    var buffer = image.GetPlanes()[0].Buffer;
                //    byte[] frameData = new byte[buffer.Remaining()];
                //    buffer.Get(frameData);

                //    _activity.ProcessFrame(frameData); // Process captured frame
                //}
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(MainActivity.TAG, "Error processing image: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                image?.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}

And my Encoder class looks like below,
 public class MediaCodecEncoder
{
    private const string TAG = nameof(MediaCodecEncoder);
    private const string MIME_TYPE = "video/avc";
    private const int I_FRAME_INTERVAL = 1;

    private MediaCodec mediaCodec;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int timeoutUSec = 10000;
    private long frameIndex = 0;
    private byte[] spsPpsInfo;
    private byte[] yuv420;
    private int frameRate;
    private int yStride;
    private int cStride;
    private int ySize;
    private int cSize;
    private int halfWidth;
    private int halfHeight;
    private readonly ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new();

    public MediaCodecEncoder() { }

    public async Task<bool> Init(int width, int height, int framerate, int bitrate)
    {
        try
        {
            mediaCodec = MediaCodec.CreateEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = SelectCodec(MIME_TYPE);
        if (codecInfo == null)
            return false;

        MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities capabilities = codecInfo.GetCapabilitiesForType(MIME_TYPE);
        bool isSupport = false;

        foreach (var format in capabilities.ColorFormats)
        {
            if (format == (int)MediaCodecCapabilities.Formatyuv420semiplanar)
            {
                isSupport = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isSupport)
            return false;

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.halfWidth = width / 2;
        this.halfHeight = height / 2;
        this.frameRate = framerate;

        //this.yStride = (int)Math.Ceiling(width / 16.0f) * 16;
        //this.cStride = (int)Math.Ceiling(width / 32.0f) * 16;
        //this.ySize = yStride * height;
        //this.cSize = cStride * height / 2;

        // Ensure proper alignment for stride calculations
        this.yStride = width;
        this.cStride = width;
        this.ySize = yStride * height;
        this.cSize = cStride * height / 2;

        this.yuv420 = new byte[width * height * 3 / 2];

        
        //MediaFormat formatAvc = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        //MediaFormat formatAvc = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 1920, 1080);
        //int colorFormat = (int)Android.Media.MediaCodecCapabilities.Formatsurface; //will be a graphic buffer data reference
        //int videoBitRate = 2000000;
        //int fps = 25;
        //int iFrameInterval = 2;

        var mediaFormat = MediaFormat.CreateVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, width, height);
        mediaFormat.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyBitRate, bitrate);
        mediaFormat.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyFrameRate, framerate);
        mediaFormat.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyColorFormat, (int)Android.Media.MediaCodecCapabilities.Formatyuv420semiplanar);//Formatyuv420sp COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible
        mediaFormat.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyIFrameInterval, 1);

        mediaCodec.Configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodecConfigFlags.Encode);
        mediaCodec.Start();
        return true;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        try
        {
            mediaCodec?.Stop();
            mediaCodec?.Release();
        }
        catch
        {
            // Handle exceptions if needed
        }
    }

    public async Task<byte[]> OfferEncoder(byte[] input)
    {
        NV21toYUV420SemiPlanar(input, yuv420, width, height);
        //YV12toYUV420PackedSemiPlanar(input, yuv420, width, height);
        try
        {
            var inputBuffers = mediaCodec.GetInputBuffers();
            var outputBuffers = mediaCodec.GetOutputBuffers();
            int inputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.DequeueInputBuffer(-1);
            if (inputBufferIndex >= 0)
            {
                long pts = ComputePresentationTime(frameIndex, frameRate);
                var inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
                inputBuffer.Clear();
                inputBuffer.Put(yuv420, 0, yuv420.Length);
                mediaCodec.QueueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, yuv420.Length, pts, 0);
                frameIndex++;
            }

            MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new();
            int outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.DequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, timeoutUSec);

            while (outputBufferIndex >= 0)
            {
                var outputBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];
                var outData = new byte[bufferInfo.Size];
                outputBuffer.Get(outData);

                if (spsPpsInfo == null)
                {
                    var spsPpsBuffer = ByteBuffer.Wrap(outData);
                    if (spsPpsBuffer.GetInt(0) == 0x00000001)
                    {
                        spsPpsInfo = new byte[outData.Length];
                        System.Array.Copy(outData, 0, spsPpsInfo, 0, outData.Length);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    outputStream.Write(outData);
                }

                mediaCodec.ReleaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
                outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.DequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, timeoutUSec);
            }

            var ret = outputStream.ToByteArray();
            if (ret.Length > 5 && ret[4] == 0x65) // Key frame needs SPS/PPS
            {
                outputStream.Reset();
                outputStream.Write(spsPpsInfo);
                outputStream.Write(ret);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            // Handle exceptions
        }

        var finalRet = outputStream.ToByteArray();
        outputStream.Reset();
        return finalRet;
    }

    private void NV21toYUV420SemiPlanar(byte[] nv21, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height)
    {
        if (nv21 == null || yuv420sp == null) return;

        int frameSize = width * height;
        int qFrameSize = frameSize / 4;

        // Y
        Array.Copy(nv21, 0, yuv420sp, 0, frameSize);

        // UV
        for (int i = 0; i < qFrameSize; i++)
        {
            yuv420sp[frameSize + i * 2] = nv21[frameSize + i * 2 + 1]; // U
            yuv420sp[frameSize + i * 2 + 1] = nv21[frameSize + i * 2]; // V
        }
    }

    public byte[] YV12toYUV420PackedSemiPlanar(byte[] input, byte[] output, int width, int height)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            System.Array.Copy(input, yStride * i, output, yStride * i, yStride);

        for (int i = 0; i < halfHeight; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < halfWidth; j++)
            {
                output[ySize + (i * halfWidth + j) * 2] = input[ySize + cSize + i * cStride + j];
                output[ySize + (i * halfWidth + j) * 2 + 1] = input[ySize + i * cStride + j];
            }
        }

        return output;
    }

    private static MediaCodecInfo SelectCodec(string mimeType)
    {
        int numCodecs = MediaCodecList.CodecCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < numCodecs; i++)
        {
            var codecInfo = MediaCodecList.GetCodecInfoAt(i);
            if (!codecInfo.IsEncoder)
                continue;

            foreach (var type in codecInfo.GetSupportedTypes())
            {
                if (type.Equals(mimeType, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    return codecInfo;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private long ComputePresentationTime(long frameIndex, int frameRate)
    {
        return 132 + frameIndex * 1000000 / frameRate;
    }
}

Any help with this encoding is much appreciated.
